# Implication, a necessary condition, a sufficient condition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Taken from elementary mathematics I am little confused as to conversion of below implications:

**Q 1.)** A necessary condition for Indian team to win a cricket match is that the selection committee selects an all rounder.

Solution: q is necessary for p
p: Indian team wins a cricket match
q: The selection committee selects an all rounder.
if p then q
"If the teams wins cricket match then selection committee selects an all rounder"

My Solution:
"If the selection committee selects an all rounder then the team wins cricket match."

**Q 2.)** A sufficient condition for Tara to visit New Delhi is that she goes to the Rashtrapati Bhawan (a building in new delhi).
p: Tara goes to the Rashtrapati Bhawan
q: She visits New Delhi
Solution: If Tara goes to Rashtrapati Bhawan, then she visits new Delhi.

My solution:
"If Tara visits New Delhi, then she goes to Rashtrapati Bhawan".

Can anyone please guide me why my solutions are wrong in both the above cases? What am I missing in my logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing necessary and sufficient.

$p$ is necessary for $q$ means than $q$ can't hold unless $p$ does.  ("$q$ needs $p$".)  So if $q$ is true, then $p$ must be true.  That is $q\rightarrow p$.

$p$ is sufficient for $q$ means that if $p$ holds then $q$ does.  ("$p$ is enough for $q$".) So, if $p$ is true, so also is $q$. That is,  $p\rightarrow q$.

**EDIT**

In reply to OP's comment.

The first statement says Q is necessary for P, not P is necessary for Q.  The statement means that India can't win unless the committee selects an all-rounder, doesn't it?

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I am confused as to how p & q are chosen in both the statements. P: Indian team wins the match , Q: Selection committee selects an all rounder. The question says p is necessary for q, so q->p should be If selection committee selects and all rounder then Indian team wins the match? Still confused a bit why original answer is different.